# SQL Server : USE instruction in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to execute this query in a stored procedure, but I get 2 errors :

> a database of USE instruction not allowed in a procedure, function, or
> a trigger.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'. (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: 154).

My code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_copytable_TEST]
    @SourceServer nvarchar(255),
    @SourceDatabase nvarchar(255),
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(255),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                         AND TABLE_NAME = 'TablesLog_TEST') 
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TablesLog_TEST] 
            (
                [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
                [SourceServer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                [SourceDatabase] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                [SourceSchema] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                [source] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                [destination] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
                [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
                [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                [type] [smallint] NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
        
        INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST 
            SELECT 
                @id, @SourceServer, @SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 
                'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                'Start Copy', 1 
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST 
                SELECT 
                    @id, @SourceServer, @SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 
                    'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                    'try 1', 1

            -- Create destination schema if it doesn't exist
            SELECT @SQL = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = [' + @DestinationSchema + '])
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = N'USE ['+ @SourceDatabase +']; 
                                EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '+ @DestinationSchema +' '')'
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
            END'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL         

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST 
            SELECT @id, @SourceServer, @SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 
            'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), 0

    END CATCH

     --Return value:
    SELECT 1;
END
```

Someone can help me please?

Best regards

Slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slim

This code will work

```
    SELECT @SQL = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = ''' + @DestinationSchema + ''')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

            SELECT @SQL = N''USE ['+ @SourceDatabase +']; 
                            EXEC(''''CREATE SCHEMA '+ @DestinationSchema +' '''')''
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        END'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

As Sandip spotted you need to declare the @SQL variable in your dynamic code. When you use sp_executesql to run the dynamic code, it is effectively running in isolation to your main stored proc, and thus knows nothing about any variables declared previously. You'll see I've added a few more single quotes to get everything working; also replaced the [] in the SELECT statement so that @DestinationSchema appears as text, and not a column name.

As an aside, do you know how to use the [debug tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SQL Server Management Studio? Type the following

```
EXEC usp_copytable_TEST 'SourceServer', 'SourceDatabase', 'SourceSchema', 'DestinationSchema'
```

on its own in a new query window. Instead of pressing F5 to execute, press ALT+F5, this will invoke a debug session and you can now step through the code line by line, watch variables and so on. You'll find this very helpful as you can see the values of your dynamic SQL strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
USE [CORE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_copytable_TEST]
    @SourceServer nvarchar(255),
    @SourceDatabase nvarchar(255),
    @SourceSchema nvarchar(255),
    @DestinationSchema nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

    BEGIN
        If NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'  AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TablesLog_TEST') 
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TablesLog_TEST](
            [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
            [SourceServer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [SourceDatabase] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [SourceSchema] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [source] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
            [destination] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
            [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
            [type] [smallint] NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST SELECT @id, @SourceServer,@SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Start Copy', 1 

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST SELECT @id, @SourceServer,@SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'try 1', 1

        -- Create destination schema if it doesn't exist
        SELECT @SQL = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = [' + @DestinationSchema + '])
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = N''USE ['+ @SourceDatabase +']; 
                                EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '+ @DestinationSchema +' '')''
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
            END'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL         

    END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO dbo.TablesLog_TEST SELECT @id, @SourceServer,@SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, 'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), 0

        END CATCH
     --Return value:
    SELECT 1;
    END
END
```

Comment: Hello Sandip Patel, Hello Paul Bambury, 

Thank you for your help!
I tried, but I got a message that said, to declare a variable @SQL.
ERROR: The scalar variable "@SQL" must be declared. 
Yet it is already declared at the beginning of my program !!

I tried to declare but it do not like it :(

have you another solution?

Comment: You have to declare that variable inside dynamic query statement (red text block)

Comment: Thank you @Sandip Patel for your help
Thank you Paul Bambury for your help
It work!!!
The problem was missing quotation marks when building my dynamic SQL.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if answer helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some quotation marks when building your dynamic SQL

Try this

```
SELECT @SQL = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = [' + @DestinationSchema + '])
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = N''USE ['+ @SourceDatabase +']; 
                                EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '+ @DestinationSchema +' '')''
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
            END'
```

Comment: Hello Paul,
when i execute the stored procedure, i've this error message :
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" linked server "MyServerName, 10001" returned message "Deferred prepare couldn't be completed.".
and in the log i have :
ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'SourceDatabase_NAME'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Sandip Patel for your help,
Thank you Paul Bambury for your help
It work!!!
The problem was missing quotation marks when building my dynamic SQL.
Like this:
`--Create Temporary table
SELECT @SQL ='SELECT * INTO SANDBOX.dbo.TempTables FROM OPENQUERY(['+@SourceServer+'],
                        ''
                        SELECT * FROM ICTNONID.information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA = '''''+@SourceSchema+'''''
                        '')
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT in (SELECT IGNORENAME FROM CORE.dbo.CopyTablesProdIgnore where IGNORETYPE = ''TABLE'' AND schemaname = '''+@SourceSchema+''') 
        '
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`